# solvePnP throws error: (-215:Assertion failed) src.size == dst.size && src.channels() == dst.channels() in function 'cvConvertScale'

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, opencv-solvepnp, camera-projection

I have 4 world coordinate points of a box and their image points . I'm trying to calculate the pose of the camera but I'm getting an error

```
File c:\Users\nmorsi200\AppData\Local\Temp\Prog6_4.py", line 292, in <module>
    cv.solvePnP(objectPoints,imagePoints,cameraMatrix,distCoeffs)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\core\src\convert_c.cpp:113: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src.size == dst.size && src.channels() == dst.channels() in function 'cvConvertScale
```

Here is my code:

```
imagePoints = np.float32([[[ 544 ,337 ],
        [ 886 ,337   ],
        [886 ,781],
        [ 544 ,781 ]]])


objectPoints = np.float32([[[ 430 ,-210,90 ],
        [ 430 ,-110 ,90  ],
        [580 ,-210,90],
        [ 886 ,-110,90 ]]])

cameraMatrix = np.float32([ 1.5968554012182622e+04, 0., 5.9163145834154648e+02, 0.,
       1.0919346214593939e+04, 8.3519145165493478e+02, 0., 0., 1. ])

distCoeffs = np.float32([ 3.1817705820413217e+01, -2.4334106040843017e+03,
       -5.7690325903983741e-01, -8.4352650966664180e-02,
       -1.9337299660588971e+04 ])

cv.solvePnP(objectPoints,imagePoints,cameraMatrix,distCoeffs)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your camera matrix is a 1-D array when it *should* be a 2-D array of shape `(3,3)`. OpenCV requires this shape. It does not accept a flat array.

```
cameraMatrix = np.float32([ ... ]).reshape((3,3))
```